# How can I build mod_wsgi 3.3 on Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mod-wsgi

How can I build **mod_wsgi 3.3** on Ubuntu 8.04?

Answer (score 1):

By following the installation instructions on the mod_wsgi site or the 'README' included with the source code.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide